# Archlinux HDMI Audio-Only Output Unplugged Unavailable

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I'm trying to play some audio through HDMI to a sound system ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09H5GJCML](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09H5GJCML)). On the back of the speakers, by the HDMI-shaped hole, it says "ARC". I'm driving it with a laptop running arch linux, XFCE4, and pulse audio. When I plug in HDMI and set the speaker to "ARC" mode, pavucontrol shows the HDMI settings as "unplugged unavailable":

[image: pavucontrol unplugged unavailable]

I've run a few tests including

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5; do
    echo "doing 1,$i";
    speaker-test -l 1 -c 6 -D hdmi:HDMI,"$i";
done;
```

(`aplay -l` shows

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: 92HD93BXX Analog [92HD93BXX Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`aplay -L` shows

```
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
lavrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Libav/FFmpeg Library
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
speex
    Plugin using Speex DSP (resample, agc, denoise, echo, dereverb)
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
default
    Default ALSA Output (currently PulseAudio Sound Server)
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD93BXX Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD93BXX Analog
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD93BXX Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD93BXX Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD93BXX Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD93BXX Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD93BXX Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD93BXX Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
usbstream:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH
    USB Stream Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=1
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=2
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=4
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 4
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=5
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 5
    HDMI Audio Output
usbstream:CARD=HDMI
    HDA ATI HDMI
    USB Stream Output
```

)

According to a post I saw, I installed `sof-firmware' and 'alsa-ucm-conf` after which `dmesg | grep sof;` says

```
[    0.074515] software IO TLB: area num 8.
[    0.389221] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
[    0.389222] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x00000000c670a000-0x00000000ca70a000] (64MB)
```

`pacmd list-sinks` looks like so:

```
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 8
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-surround>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: IDLE
        suspend cause: (none)
        priority: 9030
        volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   rear-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   rear-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-center: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   lfe: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 39.72 ms
        max request: 20 KiB
        max rewind: 20 KiB
        monitor source: 9
        sample spec: s16le 6ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
                     Surround 5.1
        used by: 0
        linked by: 1
        configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 1999.82 ms
        card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
        module: 6
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
                alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "3"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0xf7e60000 irq 33"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1002"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
                device.product.id = "aab0"
                device.product.name = "Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]"
                device.string = "hdmi:1"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "1058304"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "529152"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "hdmi-surround"
                device.profile.description = "Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)"
                device.description = "Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series] Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        ports:
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        active port: <hdmi-output-0>
```

(I have the built-in output disabled)

and `pacmd list-cards` says

```
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 6
        properties:
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0xf7e60000 irq 33"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1002"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
                device.product.id = "aab0"
                device.product.name = "Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]"
                device.string = "1"
                device.description = "Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        profiles:
                output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra5: Digital Stereo (HDMI 6) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra5: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra5: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 600, available: no)
                off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <output:hdmi-surround>
        sinks:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-surround/#8: Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series] Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)
        sources:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-surround.monitor/#9: Monitor of Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series] Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)
        ports:
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-5: HDMI / DisplayPort 6 (priority 5400, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

(I left out the built in one)

But pavucontrol output looks the same and there is still no sound.
I'm wondering if there's anything special I need to do because of "ARC"? Is it different than "just" sending audio over HDMI? Any suggestions would be helpful, or maybe you see something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC = Audio Return Channel. It is used to allow transferring audio *in the opposite direction to the main signal*, i.e. if you are using HDMI to transfer a signal (audio, video or both) from device A to B, ARC could be used to transfer audio from B to A.

For example, you might have an ARC-capable home theatre amplifier plugged into an ARC-capable TV with a HDMI cable. When viewing something from a source connected to the amplifier, it would send a regular (non-ARC) HDMI video+audio signal to the TV, although you might prefer having the amplifier handle the audio with its better speakers, so the TV would actually use only the video part of the signal.

But when watching TV transmissions, the ARC would come into play: the ARC would transmit audio of the TV channel back to the amplifier, so you could use the multi-channel speakers plugged into the amplifier to hear the sound of the TV. At the same time, the same HDMI cable could optionally be used to transmit the amplifier's on-screen menu displays to the TV.

Since your ATI display adapter is purely a HDMI *output* (which means its ARC capability, if it had one, would be an *audio input*), the use of the ARC mode is not applicable here. To send audio from a computer's HDMI output to the speakers, you would use the "primary signal" of the HDMI, not the reverse-direction ARC.

Try selecting a non-ARC HDMI mode for the speakers, if possible.

Comment: "...its ARC capability, if it had one, would be an audio input..." I understand the distinction you're making here. I think you're right, and I don't think the speakers have a non-ARC HDMI mode. I'll purchase an audio extractor: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00XJITK7E and use spdif to send audio to the speakers. Thank you.

Comment: That's probably the best you can do, then. I found what seems to be [the user's guide for your speakers](https://manuals.plus/bobtot/b901-5-1-channel-home-theater-system-with-led-light-effects-manual#component_connections) and it makes no mention of HDMI at all. Perhaps the models sold in different geographical regions have different features?